# SQL Server 2008 R2 and copy-only default value in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

We are using Tivoli Storage Manager for taking backups of the database but sometimes our consultants need to take separate backup copies of the database using Management Studio. If they forget to mark the "copy-only" flag in Management Studio they will mess up the Tivoli's backups (we are running our databases in FULL-recovery mode).

Is there a way to set the default value of the Copy-Only flag to true in the Management Studio's "Back Up Database"-window?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of SQL Server Management studio is obligatory?
Prepare a database backup SQL script with all necessary options (BACKUP DATABASE ... WITH COPY_ONLY) and create a shortcut starting [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility with this script for this consultant.